# Direct communication between iPhone users

Tags: iphone, notifications

I'm new to iPhone programming. So far I've only written a couple of simple apps just to get the hang of it. In a short time I will have an assignment to write an app that will let iPhone users communicate directly using short messages, and probably they will add a requirement to be able to send files to each other attached to the messages. Of course this sounds a lot like a mail client. For several reasons the client does not want to use mail, if possible, and attaching files would leave SMS messaging out. I've been reading Apple's documentation on local, push and broadcast notifications. Would any of these be the way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

User bonjour if you are one the same network: http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/. Otherwise it sounds like you want to use Push. I'd recommend checking out [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/)